# Runtime error: Tournaments is not defined

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, typescript2.0

The App is developed with Ionic 3. I am unable to retrieve the data from the Firebase. When I try to call the Api with function, it shows the error, that it shows it is not defined..
[image: Output]
Is there any way I could solve this pic. Also, ionViewDidUnload is not working in Ionic 3. I also tried with Event import still I didn't get it.

**Tournaments.ts**

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

    import { TeamsPage } from '../teams/teams';

    import { EliteApi } from '../../shared/elite-api'

    @IonicPage()
    @Component({
      selector: 'page-tournaments',
      templateUrl: 'tournaments.html',
    })
    export class TournamentsPage {

      tournaments : any;

      constructor(
      public navCtrl: NavController, 
      public navParams: NavParams, 
      private eliteApi : EliteApi) {
      }

      ionViewDidLoad(){
        this.eliteApi.getTournaments().then(data => this.tournaments = data );
      }

      itemTapped($event, tourney){
      this.navCtrl.push(TeamsPage, tourney);
      }

    }
```

**elite-api.ts**

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

    @Injectable()
    export class EliteApi{

        private baseUrl = 'https://elite-schedule-c1e63.firebaseio.com//';

        constructor(private http: Http){}

        getTournaments(){
            return new Promise(resolve => {
                this.http.get('${this.baseUrl}'/tournaments.json)
                    .subscribe((res: Response) => resolve(res.json()));
            });

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because the **entire url** should be between `` (right now the `/tournaments.json` part is not). So in the `elite-api.ts` file, change the `getTournaments()` method like this:

```
    getTournaments(){
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/tournaments.json`) // <- Like this :)
                .subscribe((res: Response) => resolve(res.json()));
        });

    }
```

Comment: I asked another one. Why ionViewDidUnload is not working in Ionic 3?

Comment: `ionViewDidLoad ` or `ionViewDidUnload`? @PerinbanParameshwaran

Comment: `ionViewDidUnload` does not exist btw. **[Here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#lifecycle-events)** you can find the entire list of lifecycle events @PerinbanParameshwaran

Comment: [link](https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=ionic2-angular2-typescript-mobile-apps&author=steve-michelotti&name=ionic2-angular2-typescript-mobile-apps-m4&clip=5&mode=live) In this course I have seen it. They have used that life cycle event ionViewDidUnload and its in Ionic 1

Comment: check this [link](https://imgur.com/a/OIZdB) In this image check the console. It will be used.Maybe I think in this version they removed it. Then how to unload the View which we load it?

Comment: Yes but that's an older version of Ionic. What happens if you use `ionViewWillUnload` instead? The effect should be the same. @PerinbanParameshwaran

Comment: Ok I will try it...Thanks bro